# Horizontal website scrolling with overflows hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

Trying to create a horizontal website. The idea is have navigation and footer sections static while the body can be scrolled left/right..

[Here is an example.](http://s3.sitepoint.com/examples/sidescroll/demo4.html)

However, it's not quite what I need. This one scrolls the whole page and the navbar is fixed.

Here is a mockup layout of what I want to achieve:

[image: layout]

And if user clicks navigation for body page 2:

[image]

So I began testing via Inspect Element in Chrome on that website above, I tried the following css:

```
body { max-width: 1000px; overflow: hidden; }
.panel { display: inline; }
```

Which I thought would do the trick, but it simply makes the whole page vertical. So then I added a `div id="top"` to encapsulate `home newsletter directions contact` and css:

```
body { max-width: 1000px; overflow: hidden; }
.panel { display: inline; }
#top { width: 10000px }
```

Which also didn't do the trick!

Ideally I'd like the page not to be able to scroll at all, and only animate/scroll left/right when a user clicks on a navigation link.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: why not use something [like this](http://kevinbatdorf.github.io/codaslider/) but style it so your slides are your pages

Comment: @Ubobo check this [Simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Dy2SU/2/) You don't really have to use a plugin for simple page transitions..

Comment: @Ubobo check this [Simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Dy2SU/) You don't really have to use a plugin for simple page transitions..

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at what you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/R7w5e/

To enable scrolling, remove

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

To manually set the scroll position, change

```
#content { left: -OFFSET; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just giving an idea to start with, You can do this using css3 `transform` property.

Keep each pages content inside a div, translate it `100%` so that it'll go outside the viewport, when you want to display it translate it back to `0%`.

Or scale it to 0, and when you want to display it, scale it back to 1.

*You'll have to play with `position` `z-index` etc*

Maybe something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Dy2SU/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got

http://jsfiddle.net/Shwunky/jkaMC/

These properties made it work:

```
html, body {
    width: 300%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;}
.panel {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%
    float: left;}
```

If you remove the overflow, you can see that they are aligned horizontally. What I don't understand is that even though the panel width is 33%, the width of each panel =/= the 33% of 300% (~100%), making the width of each panel >100% of the viewport width of the browser.

The header and footer both have fixed position so that they will always be on screen.

The paragraphs are relative positioned and have a top offset so that they would not touch the header.

I don't know about the animation, however, but I think this is basically what you need.